# How to convert Less to Scss?

Tags: sass, less

I have to use a converter, but it is very limited.

http://hallotheme.com/less2scss

Any idea how to convert from LESS to SCSS better?

Comment: Depends on what you wish to convert. But I assume the limitation are due to the fact that LESS is not as programming heavy as SASS. I didn't take a close look at the tool you are using. Let me know where it fails or what you try to convert...

Comment: That url you posted in your question is a known "attack page" according to Firefox, you probably shouldn't use it. You can convert LESS to SCSS manually by converting @'s to $'s and writing your LESS mixins in SCSS format, and fix any SCSS errors as you go (compile as you go to get the errors).

Answer (score 32):

The less2sass converter is pretty good and maintained https://www.npmjs.com/package/less2sass

Install it (you need https://nodejs.org/en/ on your system)

```
npm install -g less2sass
```

Once installed you can simply run

```
less2sass <path_to_less_file_or_directory>
```

Comment: I am trying to install this but getting error E404 Not found. I have installed latest node js V11.9.0 on my windows. Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: Note that, `-g` option is `--global` => installs globally, not locally, if you want to install just inside your project, remove it, if you want to install is globally, you may need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 10):

this works okayish:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-scss-convertor

```
npm install -g less-scss-convertor
less-scss-convertor src\less
```

creates src\less\scss

Comment: Nice to see this :) Love to see people using my package :)

Answer (score 5):

This online option seems to work well.  Paste in an entire file to convert it.

https://less2scss.awk5.com

Answer (score 2):

The one that worked best for me is this:
https://github.com/debba/less2scss

```
npm install less2scss --global
less2scss -s ./less_folder  -d ./scss_folder -r -e 'node_modules,vendor'
```

I just tried it and it seems I don't have to change anything on the converted files. You can exclude folders, it works recursively and you can define a target folder. Love the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using parts of Bootstraps's converter to create your own:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/tasks/converter/less_conversion.rb

However in most cases there will always be some cleanup you need to do manually.

Comment: Thank for answer! How to use it ?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to put together your own custom converter, but you can pick the important parts from the bootstrap converter. It might be hard for you if you don't know Ruby.