# SCSS ampersand operator

Tags: sass

I'm migrating from LESS to SCSS.

In LESS I can do this:

```
.btn {
  a&.disabled,
  fieldset[disabled] a& {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

CSS result:

```
a.btn.disabled,
fieldset[disabled] a.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

What is the SCSS equivalent of that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522554/how-to-convert-less-to-scss

Comment: Tried that. It compiles to `a &.disabled` and `fieldset[disabled] a &` which is wrong.

Comment: http://www.freecodeformat.com/css-less-sass.php

Comment: As per the link I shared, the SCSS equivalent is same as your generated CSS

Comment: So I think it's not possible in SCSS, I have to write pure CSS.

Comment: You may put your CSS into an SCSS file and it should work. Check [THIS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) for SCSS basics and examples

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084757/sass-scss-nesting-and-multiple-classes/11084798#11084798

Comment: There is not SASS equivalent for this. And the reason is, this notation should be about nesting (maintaining structure of parent/child nodes). When you arbitrarily concatenate selectors like this, I can guarantee you that you will lose the overview of your code pretty quickly in large projects. If you need to prepend an `a` just to make your selector more specific this already hints to problems in the structure of your css.

Comment: @Christoph thanks, this is actually from Bootstrap 3 code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**SCSS:**

```
.btn {
  //  move content out of `.btn` nesting 
  @at-root {
    //  use interpolation to `glue` a and & together 
    a#{&}.disabled,
    fieldset[disabled] a#{&} {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS Output:**

```
a.btn.disabled,
fieldset[disabled] a.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```